# Uniquely naming files via a shell script

Tags: bash, shell

i am trying to make a bash script that goes through a specified directory, finds files, sorts their contents, and then creates a new file. the ONLY problem I am running into now is how do I give each file a different name. code:

```
find $1 -name '*.grd' -exec sort -k 2,2 {}> {}.std \;
```

Answer (score 3):

When you do your redirection inside the `find` command, the shell performs the redirect only once, before starting `find`. Since `-exec` directly uses the `execv()` call to invoke a child -- with no shell -- redirections within its arguments will not be honored. (Redirections such as `>file` are performed by the calling shell, not by the operating system as part of the execution process).

For the most control, don't try to use `find -exec`, but directly process the results in shell:

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' filename; do
  sort -k2,2 <"$filename" >"${filename}.std"
done < <(find "$1" -name '*.grd' -print0)
```

Alternately, if you *do* insist on using `find -exec`, have it launch a shell itself, and do the processing and redirection there:

```
find "$1" -name '*.grd' -exec bash -c \
  'while (( $# )); do sort -k2,2 <"$1" >"$1.std"; shift; done' _ {} +
```

Other approaches are available on [the UsingFind page on the Wooledge wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind) (see in particular sections 5 through 8).

Comment: A bit confusing at first as I am new to scripting. code seems to work but I need to be able to explain it properly. can you clarify the IFS.

Comment: @user3344763 Clearing IFS prevents `read` from stripping trailing whitespace, which it does by default -- resulting in bugs if your filenames end in spaces or tab characters. Similarly, the `-d ''` argument to read tells it to expect NUL-delimited content, which makes your code safe if filenames contain newlines (which, yes, are legal on UNIX). The `-print0` argument to find, in turn, tells it to use NUL delimiters when emitting filenames.

Comment: @user3344763 ...in general, it's a good idea to test any shell script against filenames with whitespace -- particularly trailing whitespace -- newlines, etc., before saying that it "works"; there are lots of easy pitfalls and mistakes to fall into if not careful.